# tool to output xy from an input xy, distant, and angle

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, distance, coordinates, angles

I want to build a tool where you provide coordinates, distance, and angle for input and it outputs coordinates, no feature necessary, using the distance and angle from the input coordinates.

How do I build this?

I am using ArcMap for desktop 10.4.1

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be no chit chat in questions asked here.  For example, yours contained unnecessary verbiage like "My question is" and "Thanks" that I have removed.  Please do not roll that back.  Also, the first tag on any ArcMap question should be [tag:arcgis-desktop] if you want your question to be seen by the ArcGIS Desktop product experts who use the ArcMap application.

Answer (score 3):

This python code will do it using sine and cosine. 
Python requires radians for trig functions so it converts your angle in degrees to radians first.

```
def Translate(X,Y,angle,distance):                #defines function
    # 0 degrees = North, 90 = East, 180 = South, 270 = West
    dY = distance*math.cos(math.radians(angle))   #change in y 
    dX = distance*math.sin(math.radians(angle))   #change in x 
    Xfinal = X + dX                               
    Yfinal = Y + dY
    return Xfinal, Yfinal
```

Comment: Can you explain why x uses cosine and y uses sine? I have seen this answer before on other questions and I can simply use the calculation but I do not understand why it is being done

Comment: I have edited my answer. Cosine divides the coordinate adjacent to the angle over the total distance, Sine divides the coordinate opposite the angle by the total distance. I use python for both physics and geography and my answer was using the angles which are standard in physics with 0 degrees pointing to the right (+ x axis) and angles going counter clockwise. In geography 0 degrees points north (+ y axis) and angles go clockwise so the trig functions are reversed. dX = Dist * sin(Angle) and dY = Dist * cos(Angle).

Answer (score 0):

ArcGIS has a tool that does most of what you are after called [Bearing Distance to Line](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/bearing-distance-to-line.htm). All you would need to do is extract the coordinates from the end point on the line created from the tool using a [Search Cursor](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm).

Comment: Yeah, but that outputs a feature, which I don't want.  I just want an output box that displays the new coordinates